# Does a figure which has a contour plot have a systematic function to define it?

Tags: scalar-fields

Does a figure which has a contour plot have a systematic function to define it?  I mean I am plotting a contour plot (the contour plot which shows z slices in x-y graph) of a figure like (suppose)  mount everest. Does it necessary have a systematic function f(x, y)  to define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is not a systematic way to plot the contour map of a terrain.  In particular, many terrains are not a function of longitude and latitude; that is, there may be multiple heights at any point.  So it's not a function at all.

However, for nicely behaved terrains (e.g. Mount Everest), one can make the contour plots in a systematic way.

A levelset of a function are all the points where the function equals a specific value.  For example, the 0-levelset of a function f is the set $\{x: f(x)=0\}$.  Any levelset can be drawn with the marching squares algorithm.  So, to make a contour-map, one would choose the values of each contour that one would like to draw, and then use the marching-squares algorithm to draw those contours.

I hope that helps.  :)

Comment: Obviously this helps.